# What's a good way to display a custom raster basefile in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, raster, geoserver

I have a land cover raster that I'd like to display as part of an OpenLayers based application.  I'm able to load the raster directly as a PNG but my OpenLayers application becomes VERY slow.  I think I want something that can tile the raster and send level of detail tiles that OpenLayers can fetch, but I'm not sure since I'm a GIS newbie.

Is this something that GeoServer can handle automatically?  I'd love to be able to load rasters and shapefiles onto the server then link to those layers in OpenLayers.  Is this the correct approach?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would say you have 2 options.

1/ Use a WMS server.

- You can then use [tilecache](http://tilecache.org/) with openlayers. [Here](https://web.archive.org/web/20150717043102/http://dev.openlayers.org:80/releases/OpenLayers-2.11/examples/tilecache.html) is an example.
- [Mapproxy](https://mapproxy.org/) is also an option. You will find a very recente [tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20130601085647/http://2011.foss4g.org:80/sessions/tech-session-open-12) from FOSS4G2011.
- Finally [GeoWebCache](https://web.archive.org/web/20220804012538/https://www.geowebcache.org/) can also be useful to you. Here a [guide](https://web.archive.org/web/20161014104014/https://oegeo.wordpress.com/2008/05/20/the-5-minute-guide-to-setting-up-geoserver-and-geowebcache-on-windows/) to set it up with geoserver.

2/ Or use [gdal2tiles](https://gdal.org/gdal2tiles.html) and display resulting tiles directly in openlayers.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, that is exactly what [GeoServer](http://geoserver.org) and the built in GeoWebCache does for you.

I'm assuming that your PNG is geocoded already (i.e. you know which area of the world it covers) in which case you'll probably want to convert it to a GeoTIFF (using [GDAL](http://gdal.org)). Check out http://demo.geo-solutions.it/share/foss4g2011/gt_raster_simone_foss4g2011.pdf for a full discussion of adding rasters to GeoServer and how to speed up their display.